# How to produce rotations with no repetitions of a volume using Euler angles?

Tags: matrices, rotations, angle

I have a volume (which can be written as an array) and need to make an algorithm to produce a set of rotations of this structure using different combinations of Euler Angles with a fixed step.
For example, I could make $36 \times 36 \times 36$ rotations by rotating the volume with step of $10^\circ$ along the $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ angles.
However, it's know that many of these produced rotations are not unique.
I need to know how to produce only unique rotations with the $3$ Euler angles given a fixed angular step. Thanks!